# Trying to evaluate integral with leftover algebraic terms

Tags: python, scipy

I'm trying to evaluate the integral

[image]

with

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import integrate




def function(tau, mu, eta):
    return np.cos(mu*tau)/(np.cosh(tau)+eta)**.5
def integrate_function(tau_min, tau_max, mu,eta):
    return integrate.quad(function, tau_min, tau_max, args=(mu,eta,))[0]


# define integration range
tau_min = 0
tau_max = 1000
# define range of a variable
eta_mu_points = np.linspace(1, 10, 100)

results = []
for eta_mu in eta_mu_points:
    value = integrate_function(tau_min, tau_max, eta_mu, eta_mu)
    results.append(value)


plt.plot(eta_mu, results)
plt.ylabel("Integral value")
plt.xlabel("a variable")
plt.show()
```

Ideally I want to perform the integration and leave mu and eta as parameters. I have tried to make them parameters varying between 1 and 10 but this hasn't worked. Any thoughts? Thank you.

Comment: So, what's wrong with your code? I think it should work fine

Comment: overflow encountered with the cosh term

Comment: okay sheet ye I fixed it, just lowered the bound a little or use bigfloat package i guess for more precision but it's k.

Comment: Glad it worked eventually!